# What happend with the light from all the galaxies visibles from an earth telescope?

Tags: astronomy, photons, universe

Supposing it's possible to see some distant galaxies with an earth telescope, then, at the tip of the telescope lens there are photons comming from the distant galaxy...

So, if I extend my hand in a dark night without visible moon, and far from city lights, photons from distant galaxies are in my hand skin... if it is true... is kind of amazing...

Then at that moment if photons of EVERY visible galaxy (from an earth telescope) are in my hand, then why my hand didn't bright? knowing (from photoelectric effect) that photons act as a whole or don't act, then why my hand didn't bright?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure, but I think this question is about what is generally known as [Olbers's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox): If, at any given moment, light from all light sources in the Universe are illuminating any given point, one might expect every point to be extremely bright.

To be precise, consider all of the light sources in a spherical shell of radius $R$ and thickness $dR$. If the Universe is uniform, the number of such sources is proportional to $R^2\,dR$. The apparent brightness of each source is proportional to $1/R^2$, so the total light striking your hand from all such sources is simply proportional to $dR$. If the Univers is infinite, then the total that results from integrating all such sources is infinite.

In reality, distant sources will be blocked by nearby sources, so the power striking your hand won't be infinite, but it will be as large as f the entire sky were filled with sources of the same temperature as a typical star. (To see this, note that every line of sight ends on the surface of a star. The surface brightness (watts per steradian) due to a source doesn't depend on distance: the brightness goes down like $1/R^2$, but so does the solid angle. So the entire sky has the surface brightness of a star.

That's the paradox. What's the resolution?

The main thing is simply that we shouldn't integrate out to $R=\infty$. The Universe has a finite age, which means we can see out only to a finite distance. If you consider only the sources within our observable volume, the integrated brightness of all those galaxies still turns out to be very small. Galaxies are luminous, but they're far away. (There's also the fact that distant sources are receding from us, so the light from them is highly redshifted.)

Comment: Isn't the fact that we are not at star temperatures  an argument in the proof that the universe is finite?

Comment: It's a proof that one of the assumptions that goes into Olbers's paradox is false. Those assumptions include that the Universe is infinite in spatial extent, infinite in age, homogeneous in space, homogeneous in time. It doesn't say which assumption is false, so it's not a proof that the Universe is finite.

Comment: The entire sky would be infinitely bright, not the brightness of a star.  You can't just "block" distant sources.  They would absorb the energy hitting them, heat up, and radiate more brightly.

Comment: But the further out you look the further back in time you see, and further back in time there was less stars right? Also we can only see up to 13.6 billion light years away so if the universe was infinite we will never know what's beyond the 13.6 billion (currently) light years

Comment: Also if you draw a point on a piece of paper and radiate many lined from the point the bugger the gaps will be between the lines, surely the same affect applies to stars? Can't some of the distant stars just nit have photons "aimed" at us.

Comment: Remember that if you go far enough, you hit the CMB. Further than that space was opaque.

Comment: Another resolution of Olbers paradox is that distant sources will have their light redshifted below the visible range.  The CMB was originally as bright as the surface of a star, after all.

Comment: I change the title, someone has edited it to add the phrase "infinite universe" I didn't  need that assumption for making the question.

Comment: If you don't assume an infinite, homogeneous, infinitely old Universe, there's no problem. Your hand is illuminated by all the galaxies in the Universe, but that need not be much.

Comment: @Ted Bunn are you sure there is no problem? I think with enough visible photons hand should shine, the eyes are very sensible to just few photon of visible wavelenght, then if my hand is illuminated with finite but millon galaxies, and every one of them send me many photons, then the number is enough high to think why it doesn't bright?.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. "With enough photons," things will look bright, but there wouldn't be enough photons. Space is big and the galaxies are far away.

Comment: @Ted Bunn your last comment is a circular reasoning, you must be right or not, but that's not a deduction. Simply knowing the Number of Visible Galaxies From a Earth Telescope, let's say NVGFET, and the minimal number of photons to see each one from a scope MNP, we are receiving NVGFET*MNP photons, Having those experimental data you can ensure (or not) that there is not enough photons